# Antlr4 Parse Number

Tags: java, antlr

I want write expression like springEl to practice.

When I input `#user.age>3` is right.

But I input `#user.age>3ww` or  `#user.age>3ww && #user.age<2` the parser not hint any error. I do not think `#user.age>3ww` is right syntax.

How to change grammar to let the parser hint `3ww` is error?

my part antlr4 grammar

```
grammar FlowExpr;

statement : expr;

expr
    :   expr (Mul|Div) expr
    |   expr (Add|Sub) expr
    |   expr BooleanOperator expr
    |   expr And expr
    |   expr Or expr
    |   Not expr
    |   object
    ;

object
    :   boolean
    |   invoker
    |   entity
    |   number
    |   String
    ;
entity : ObjectSymbol Identifier;
boolean : 'true'|'false';
invoker : entity attribute+;
attribute : Dot Identifier;
number
    :   Integer
    |   Float
    ;
Identifier :  Letter (Letter|JavaIDDigit)* ;
Integer : '-'? INT ;
Float : '-'? INT Dot [0-9]*;

Commas : ',';

BooleanOperator
    :   '>'|'>='|'<'|'<='|'=='|'!=';
Not:'!';
Dot : '.';
ObjectSymbol : '#';
WS  :   [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip ;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQl9Y.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input `2w` is being tokenised as an `Integer`- and `Identifier` token. Then the `number` parser rule consumes the `Integer` token and then stops parsing (it matches exactly 1 `Integer` token, which is what you told it to do).

If you want to force the parser to consume *all* the tokens produces by the lexer, you need it to do so by adding an `EOF` (the built-in end of file/input token). You's usually have 1 entry-rule that contains this `EOF`:

```
grammar t;

entryPoint
    : number EOF
    ;

number
    :   Integer
    |   Float
    ;
fragment INT :  '0'| [1-9][0-9]* ; 
Integer : '-'? INT ;
Float : '-'? INT Dot [0-9]*;
Dot : '.';
Identifier :  [a-zA-Z];
```

Comment: I edit issue to more clearly. Please look again to hlep me.Thanks

Comment: I try change `statement : expr;` to `statement : expr EOF;` is useful